# How to automatically update npm?

Tags: npm

Recently I've been a little bit annoyed because after building my project I get a message like this nearly EVERY DAY:

```
   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                │
   │      New patch version of npm available! 6.14.6 -> 6.14.8      │
   │   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.14.8   │
   │               Run npm install -g npm to update!                │
   │                                                                │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

so I run `npm install -g npm` and a few days later or so it's there again with a newer patch (at least I assume so, since I executed that script successfully and don't know of anything that reverts it).

I'm very happy that people are improving it, but is there an easy way for this to update itself?
Because I'd rather manually downgrade it than having to manually upgrade it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message above indicates that you are using `npm` version 6.x. That release line does not get a new release every day or even every week. In fact, the version in that message (6.14.8) was released 2 months ago. Judging from the `6.x` release history, `npm 6.x` was getting updated about once a month. Now that `7.x` is out, it will probably be less frequent. So frequent `npm` updates may not be your problem. The problem may be that `npm` updates are not sticking (or working at all) for you for whatever reason.

On the other hand, if you are using `npm` v7.x, it's a recent release that has been undergoing bug fixes every few days, but that is very likely to slow waaaay down. So one solution may be to just wait another week or two and the updates will be less frequent. (They may already be much less frequent than the were even last week.)

**All that said:** A blunt hammer solution would be to update `npm` as the first step in your build process. If you run `npm run build` as your build step, update `package.json` to add `npm install -g npm &&`  at the front of your build script. If you want to tolerate the `npm` update failing, you can change `&&` to `||` but then the message you want to go away will still show up if the `npm` installation/update fails.

If your build process involves installing Node.js, then putting `npm install -g npm` **after** the Node.js installation is the way to go. Node.js ships with `npm` and it is exceedingly likely that the version that ships with Node.js is not the most recent version.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! I was kinda suspicious from the start that something's not right there - now I finally know what this is about!